# Bean level validation on field with Jsf binding

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

**BeanOne**

```
  @NotEmpty(groups = { Group1.class })
  private String name;
```

**BeanTwo**

```
  private EditableValueHolder myBinding;
  priavet BeanOne beanOne;
```

**xhtml**

```
 <h:inputText value="#{beanTwo.beanOne.name}" binding="#{beanTwo.myBinding}"/>      
 <button class="btn btn-primary"        
         jsf:action="#{beanTwo.save}">
        Save
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
 </button>
```

When I save the validation is not happening. When I remove binding on the input element, the bean validation is working.

Is there anything wrong in my code.

Comment: Are you aware of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used?

Comment: @BalusC. Thank you. I have gone through it. I think it is a bad practice to have this on bean property.  It would be great if you can help with me any work around.

Comment: That can only be answered if you tell about the problem for which you thought that this would be the solution.